# Recursive Function - jQuery , get Links

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion

I have a problem in recursive function for listing (folders & links )
every Folder has links , and maybe every folder has subfolders too,

My problem is that i cant display the links inside thier related folders , my code is only listing the folders without the links
https://jsfiddle.net/9vxa6x8u/1/

here is my code :

```
function buildTree(jsonUrl) {

        function tree(treeData) {
            var mainUl = $('<ul>');
            $.each(treeData, function( index, folder ) {
                id = "folder"+ folder.id;
                var li =$('<li id="'+id+'" >');
                ul = $('<ul>');
                ul.append(li.text(folder.name).append(tree(folder.subFolders)));

                $.each(folder.links, function( index, link ) {
                    ul.append($('<li>').text(link.name));
                });
                mainUl.append(li);
            });
            return mainUl;
        }

        $.ajax({
           url: jsonUrl,
           dataType: "json",
           type: "get",
           success: function (data) {
                    $('#links-tree').append(tree(data));
           },
           error: function (e) {
               console.log(e)
           },
       });
}
```

Comment: How should the links be shown? Given your data structure they are a completely separate array from the `subFolders` which you are currently looping theough

Comment: In every subfolder there is its links array , here are the json data:

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ucmdt

Comment: Do you have jsFiddle for is please ?

Comment: @FadiNouh check my answer

Comment: @FadiNouh i have updated my answer check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, Is this what you want to achive. Please refer this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/juakfbre/5/)

Just made changes in following

```
function tree(treeData) {
    if (treeData) {
      var mainUl = $('<ul>');
      $.each(treeData, function(index, folder) {
        id = "folder" + folder.id;
        var li = $('<li id="' + id + '" >');
        ul = $('<ul>');
        li.text(folder.name);
        ul.append(li.text(folder.name).append(tree(folder.subFolders)).append(tree(folder.links)));

        mainUl.append(li);
      });

      return mainUl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: We are close ! ... but its giving only the last subfolder's links , because for example in 'Marcia' folder in your jsfiddle there are also links showld be shown in li also

Comment: @FadiNouh Can you please give text of link which is inside of `Marcia` folder

Comment: this is the json file ,  
https://api.myjson.com/bins/ucmdt
as we can see there are Links array in Marcia Folder but they are not displayed in your jsfiddle , Thank you for help :)

Comment: Its perfect , but just last point , inside every link <li> there is empty <ul>'s , can it be clear , the link can be only li , nothing inside it , because only the subfolders has <ul> inside them , thank you for nice help

Comment: Thank you so so so much , you saved my day